# import PDF file and insert some values to particular place in PHP

Tags: php, templates, pdf

i have design a template blank PDF file and i get some data witch is generated by using PHP mysql retrieved data i need to merge them into one PDF file and to take print.

Witch PDF plugin is good for generate PDF ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) class in your project.
and [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

Comment: or mpdf, or dompdf, or Zend_Pdf, or...

Comment: At the end you will need [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to import the template! This should be mentioned in this accepted answer!